# Running two versions of Apache Spark in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I want to be able to run Spark 2.0 and Spark 1.6.1 in cluster mode on a single cluster to be able to share resources, what are the best practices to do this? this is because I want to be able to shield a certain set of applications from code changes that rely on 1.6.1 and others on Spark 2.0.

Basically the cluster could rely on dynamic allocation for Spark 2.0 but maybe not for 1.6.1 - this is flexible.

Comment: Which resource manager are you using spark own standalone scheduler?

Comment: We don't use anything but I am open to using mesos...

Answer (score 0):

By using Docker this is possible you can run various version of Spark application, since Docker runs the application in Isolation.

Docker is an open platform for developing, shipping, and running applications. . **With Docker you can separate your applications from your infrastructure and treat your infrastructure like a managed application**.

Industries are adopting Docker since it provide this flexibility to run various version application in a single nut shell and many more

Mesos also allows to Run Docker Containers using Marathon

For more information please refer 
https://www.docker.com/
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html

Hope this helps!!!....

Comment: Yea the question there is how are ports handled with spark running cluster mode - how do I define ports and re-use executors - the whole point of sandboxing an application is to be able to use executors effectively in a spark cluster - since theres a limited number of machines and cores.